# No Database Selected Error - Don't know why

Tags: php, mysql, database

For some reason I am getting the error

> No database selected

I have no idea why this is not working, am I being blind?

```
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','myusername','mypassword');
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
```

There are no typos in the actual username, password or database name and I can't see a mistake in my code.

Suggestions are very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is the return value of `mysql_select_db('mydatabase')`?

Comment: Do you have `username` added to the `user` table? What if you try the same code with `root` user?

Comment: ok, I have been a complete muppet! I apologise for wasting everyone's time. I hadn't actually added the user to the database. Thank you @Rahul

Comment: @Ben ... Since that atleast pointed to the right direction ... I am making this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `username` added to the `user` table? What if you try the same code with `root` user?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $con);
```

in stead of:

```
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
```